# Build definition to compare branches

Tags: powershell, tfs, merge, msbuild

Not sure if I am using the correct tool/approach, but here is what I am trying to do:
We have TFS 2010 and a number of branches. A number of times we have a parent branch and a feature branch. Different teams are working on both branch, and we need to make sure that branch A(parent) is always merged in branch B(feature/child). Normally we have a manual process in place so that somebody is assigned to merge once or twice a week.

I am trying to add an automated check for this. Is it possible to create a build definition which i can execute nightly, and it can compare two branches and send an alert(or failed build), in case branch B does not have any contents of branch A?

i already have nightly build happening, so perhaps I can add something to it to do this comparison and somehow flag a failure or alert?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [tf folderdiff command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385992(v=vs.100).aspx).  So it would look something like this where you would send the output to a file to process and look for summary differences.  Perhaps you could do the summary check in the pipeline but that would be more complicated.

```
> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe' `
   folderdiff $/branchA/folder $/branchB/folder /recursive /noprompt `
   | out-file c:\temp.txt
```

You may also filter out file types you don't want to compare.

Comment: Maybe using `$vCSChangeSets = $versionControlServer.QueryHistory($locationToSearch, $latest, 0, $recursionType, $userName, $versionFrom, $versionTo, [int32]::MaxValue, $true ,$false, $false, $true)`

Comment: **tf folderdiff**, I get `tf.exe : Unable to determine the source control server.` ***error*** . Add parameter `/collection:http://MyTFSServer:8080`